# why does python console run differently to idle

Tags: python, python-3.x, debugging

Can anyone tell me why this code runs differently in python console than IDLE?

```
print('Do not press enter before the program says go.\n', end = '')
try:
    while True:
        input('Ready?')
        print('Starting', end = '')
        for i in range(secrets.randbits(3)):
            time.sleep(1)
            print(' .', end = '')
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        input('\nGo!')
        print('\nReaction: {}'.format(datetime.datetime.now()-now))
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print('Exiting.')
```

This is the output in IDLE which works the way I expect:

```
Do not press enter before the program says go.
Ready?
Starting . .
Go!

Reaction: 0:00:00.328174
```

But when in the console I get the same overall output but the dots do not show up one after the other, instead they all appear at once with go.Can anyone explain this strange behaviour. I am running Python 3.6.2 if that helps.

I do have a way to test if the program is running from IDLE or not which returns true if in idle and false if not in idle:

```
def inIDLE():
    import sys
    if 'idlelib.run' in sys.modules:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: IDLE has a few quirks; the plain console is behaving correctly. If you don't want your dots to appear all at once you can tell the console to flush its output: `print(' .', end = '', flush=True)`

Comment: Ahh, now that is the solution that I was looking for. I had no idea how to use flush but now I do. Thanks for the help @PM2Ring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it's a GUI program (running on Tkinter) IDLE has a few quirks; the plain console is actually behaving correctly, since output to `stdout` is normally line-buffered.

If you don't want your dots to appear all at once you can tell the console to flush its output:

```
print(' .', end = '', flush=True)
```

Alternatively, you can print to `stderr` which is normally not buffered:

```
import sys
#...
print(' .', end = '', file=sys.stderr)
```

In the console, you can select unbuffered `stdout` by passing the `-u` option to the interpreter, see `python3 -h` for details.